# Can't use Foursquare because it needs Google Play Services, which "is not supported by your device"

Tags: system-error, google-play-services, foursquare

I've installed [Foursquare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joelapenna.foursquared), but it does not start, instead I get the following error:

> Google Play Services, which some of your applications rely on, is not supported by your device.

I don't know what does this mean and how can I solve this issue to use the application.
I'm using Chinese phone AMOI N 821 android 4.1.1. I live in Russia.

What should I do?

Comment: Does your phone have GPS capability? Foursquare uses and requires GPS to run.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Services provides a "backbone" of sorts not just for Google apps but other apps as well. This is part of the way that Google is letting users and apps get to more "modern" Android features *without* having to wait for carriers to update their version of the OS.

I'm guessing that the phone you're using didn't come with Google apps installed.

See if you can install [Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) directly.

If so, you should be good to go.

If not, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: So my phone has this app (google play services)..

Comment: And? Did you just install it, or was it already there? Have you tried re-starting your phone? Clearing the cache on either app? Re-installing?

Comment: oh(it is incompatible with other apps using the same shared user ID(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Chinese Products does not support the Google Services as Google is not allowed in the China.
So the Only Option i see is the VPN. Try using the free VPN services.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Nexus 7. It's coproduced by Google, so it was obvious it wasn't caused by a lack of Google Apps.

In my case it was an error in the synchronization of the Google account (`settings → personal → account`). Tapping on my account, I forced the sync.

Then I closed the problematic app, restarting it. And the problem was gone.