# google play services do not support your device

Tags: google-play-services

When I open some application it says Google play services it says "Google play services which some of your applications rely n do not support or device"..what should I do about it?

Comment: What device do you have? What Android version are you running? Where do you see this message?

Comment: Similar, if not duplicate: [Can't use Foursquare because it needs Google Play Services, which "is not supported by your device"](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49910)

Answer (score 0):

Following steps helped me. May be you can try.

1. Go to Settings -> Apps
2. Find Google play
3. Click on Uninstall updates
4. Once Uninstall update is done, Open Google Play several times till it updates to latest version itself.
5. Open youtube to check if the message is gone and you are able to open youtube.

Comment: Did not help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Android 2.2 Google Play Services is not supported.

Answer (score -2):

1) Go to Settings -> Storage
        Clear the Cache (select the item and hit OK to clear it), then:

2) Go to Settings -> Date & Time
        Check the first 2 options -- if they're selected already, uncheck and re-select them; see if the time fixes itself.
        If it works, reboot the device and see if the time sticks. If not:

3) Power off the device, pull out the SIM and re-insert it, then power on the device.
        Repeat Step 2.
        If that doesn't work:

4) Try a different SIM (preferably on a different carrier).

5) Lastly, try to manually set the date to within a few minutes of the actual time, then see if it survives a reboot.

If all of that fails, I would suggest booting into recovery (while device is off, hold Power + Volume Down until you the the 'laying down android' screen) and doing a factory reset (back up your data first).

Comment: How will this help?